# Efficiency of perspective projection vs raytracing/ray casting

Tags: c++, matrix, projection, raytracing

I have a very general question. I wish to determine the boundary points of a number of objects (comprising 30-50 closed polygons (z) each having around 300 points(x,y,z)). I am working with a fixed viewport which is rotated about x,y and z-axes (alpha, beta, gamma) wrt origin of coordinate system for polygons.

As I see it there are two possibilities: perspective projection or raytracing. Perspective projection would seem to requires a large number of matrix operations for each point to determine its position is within or without the viewport.
Or given the large number of points would I better to raytrace the viewport pixels to object? 
 i.e. determine whether there is an intersection and then whether intersection occurs within or without object(s). 
In either case I will write this result as 0 (outside) or 1 (inside) to 200x200 an integer matrix representing the viewport

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 6):

Perspective projection (and then scan-converting the polygons in image coordinates) is going to be a *lot* faster.

The matrix transform that is required in the case of perspective projection (essentially the world-to-camera matrix) is required in exactly the same way when raytracing. However, with perspective projection, you're only transforming the corner points, whereas with raytracing, you're transforming *all* the points in the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response: however I still need to determine the subset of "corner points" somehow- presumably the maximum distance perpendicular to "camera lens" axis?

Comment: By "corner points", I means the vertices of the polygon. I am assuming that your polygon is defined by a list of vertices. (If that's not the case, how are your polygons defined?) To perform perspective projection on a polygon, it's enough to project the vertices; this is because a perspective projection always maps a straight line in space to a straight line in the image.

Comment: sure those (vertices) are the 50*300 (x,y,z) points: I was being a bit slow there! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use perspective projection and a perspective projection matrix to compute the position of the vertices in screen space? It's hard to understand what you want to do really. If you want to create an image of that 3D scene then with only few polygons it would be hard to see any difference anyway between ray tracing and rasterisation if your code is optimised (you will still need to use an acceleration structure for the ray tracing approach), however yes rasterisation is likely to be faster anyway.

Now if you need to compute the distance from between the eye (the camera's origin) and the geometry visible through the camera's view, the I don't see why you can't use the depth value of any sample for any pixel in the image and use the inverse of the perspective projection matrix to find its distance in camera space.

Why is speed an issue in your problem? Otherwise use RT indeed.

Most of this information can be found on www.scratchapixel.com